# How to declare and addItem to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Build the ShoppingCart class with the following specifications. Note: Some can be method stubs (empty methods) initially, to be completed in later steps.

- Private fields
- String customerName - Initialized in ddefault constructor to "none"
- String currentDate - Initialized in ddefault constructor to "January 1, 2016"
- ArrayList cartItems
- Default constructor
- Parameterized constructor which takes the customer name and date as parameters (1 pt)
- Public member methods

  - getCustomerName () accessor (1 pt)
  - getDate () accessor (1 pt)
  - addItem ()
  - Adds an item to cartItems array. Has parameter ItemToPurchase. Does not return anything.
    ...

ok so i got lost around the arrayList cartItems. I am not sure if I should declare it as a `String` or an `int`. Also not sure if how I declared it was correct or the way the asked it to be done. I also created a class called `ItemToPurchase` that goes with this and I need to create a class called `ShoppingCartManager` that has the main method. Here's what I have so far (I took some things out of the `ShoppingCart` class.)

**ItemToPurchase.java**

```
public class ItemToPurchase {

    private String itemName;

    private String itemDescription;

    private int itemPrice;

    private int itemQuantity;

    public ItemToPurchase() {
        itemName = "none";
        itemPrice = 0;
        itemQuantity = 0;
        itemDescription = "none";

    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        itemDescription = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }

    public String printItemCost() {
        String str = getName() + " " + getQuantity() + " " + getPrice() + " " + (getQuantity() * getPrice());
        return str;
    }

    public String printItemDescription() {
        String k = getName() + " " + getDescription();
        return k;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        itemName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return itemName;

    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        itemPrice = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        itemQuantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return itemQuantity;
    }

}
```

**ShoppingCart.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String customerName;
    private String currentDate;
    private ArrayList<String> cartItems = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ShoppingCart(String customerName, String currentDate) {
        customerName = "none";
        currentDate = "January 1, 2016";
    }

    public void getCustomerName() {

    }

    public void getDate() {

    }

    public void addItem(String itemName) {
        cartItems.add(itemName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me your `ArrayList` does not need to hold `int`s or `String`s, but rather `ItemToPurchase` instances. This would mean changing your `ArrayList` declaration to `private ArrayList<ItemToPurchase> cartItems = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();` This way you can add `ItemToPurchase` objects to the `ArrayList`, which I believe is what you are trying to do. Then change your `addItem` method in the `ShoppingCart` class to accept `ItemToPurchase` objects, instead of `String` objects.

```
public void addItem(ItemToPurchase item) {
    cartItems.add(item);
}
```